# What prevents Van Emde Boas trees from being more popular in real-world applications?

Tags: data-structures, van-emde-boas-trees

We know balanced trees perform insertion, deletion, and search in *O(log n)*-time, examples include

- Red-Black
- AVL
- Splay
- B-tree (and its variants).

However, when keys are integers in some limited range, it is possible to use a Van Emde Boas tree to drop these operations down to *O(log(log n))*-time, i.e., exponentially better than AVL or RB trees.
Well, this is actually the case of many real world applications.

I see lots of applications for this.
One I'd like to cite is on databases, for which creating indexes basically involves choosing between a Hash or a B*-tree.
If a Van Emde Boas tree was implemented, it would provide a halfway between these two options, theoretically improving many query optimization problems.

Why Van Emde Boas tree is not widely used as say Red-Black or B-tree since

- it's not a novelty (it was invented in 1975)
- easy to implement
- way faster than other trees

and what are the considerations about it?

Comment: Maybe because a large number of database keys are not integers in a limited range? :-) If you know the limited range, you can often make a very efficient hash function, possibly a perfect hash, and maybe even a perfect minimal hash, rendering tree structures irrelevant.

Comment: @paxdiablo Primary keys in SQL databases are almost always (initially sequential) integers of some large, but finite range (e.g. 64 bit). It's true that that one can design very efficient hash tables for such keys, but finding a perfect (let alone minimal perfect) hash requires knowing the **full** set of keys, requiring finding a new perfect hash function and re-hashing the whole table *every time* a key is added or removed. That is a much more narrow use case, in that it's only feasible for *static* sets of keys.

Comment: This code might be of interest https://github.com/6851-2021/practical-veb-tree

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The asymptotic complexity is sometimes misleading. In the case for `Van Emde Boas tree` the constant is quite large [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree#Discussion). I quote:

```
However, for small trees the overhead associated with vEB trees
is enormous: on the order of 2^(m/2)
```

There are also other cases where an algorithm with better complexity exists but it only gets better for an input so big that in practice it is almost never used e.g. linear time static RMQ.

Comment: In another context, seems like Radix-sort shares the same overhead problem when it comes to real world applications.

Comment: @CássioJandirPagnoncelli True. Radix sort has a constant factor on the order of the number of bits your values have which in most practical cases is even more than the logarithm of the number of elements you are sorting.

Comment: Another good examples of this are integer multiplication algorithms. There are few that are used for different ranges, and even few not used at all (probably yet) because there is actual practical trouble in feeding input so big they would start to overcome their worse *Big O* counter parts.

Comment: Using a hashtable for vEB tables can make vEB more efficient than binary search trees for even small trees.

Comment: When using a hashtable for vEB tables, the space taken is O(n) instead of O(M) or O(2^m).

Answer (score 15):

One of the reason is that complexity is defined not on the size of the set you store but on the size of the universe of values.
Another difference is that keys can't be arbitrary types for which you have comparison operation but must be integers.
You should not see vEB as an alternative for BST but rather as an alternative for arrays. 
An array have O(1) store and look up costs for object keyed by integers.
vEB offer O(log log M), where M is size of the universe of your values.
Now, you see vEB is not better than regular array for look ups and store but it offers O(1) min, max operations and O(log log M) prev next key operations which array does not.
It's worth to mention that the layout of vEB trees has a properties which make possible to create cache oblivious trees which are far more interesting developments of modern CS.

http://erikdemaine.org/papers/BRICS2002/paper.pdf

Comment: Don't arrays offer O(1) prev/next since they have constant time random access? If you know the position of the current item then you can get the next/previous one in constant time.

Comment: We are talking about set representation in array where  a[x] = true if x is in the set and false otherwise. So you have constant insert and membership test, but linear next/prev. If you just list the elements in the array in ascending order you have O(log N) membership test (via binary search), O(n) instert (to maintain the sorted order) and O(1) prev/next.

Comment: @quikchange by prev/next I mean predecessor and successor defined by the order of the type, not the previous next in data layout.

Comment: @quikchange only if your array is filled. If your array holds 4 elements like [1, 10, 100, 1000] and have length of 1000 moving from 1000 to its prev (100) is not O(1) but O(N).